# Open next Activity multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, google-mlkit

I'm trying to modify the MLSeries pose detection code by Google, when it reached 3 squats it will open a new activity. But, after I edit the code and ran it, it open the new activity multiple times. How I can avoid the app to open the activity multiple times when it reached certain reps?

```
    // Update {@link RepetitionCounter}s if {@code isStreamMode}.
if (isStreamMode) {
  // Feed pose to smoothing even if no pose found.
  classification = emaSmoothing.getSmoothedResult(classification);

  // Return early without updating repCounter if no pose found.
  if (pose.getAllPoseLandmarks().isEmpty()) {
    result.add(lastRepResult);
    return result;
  }

  for (RepetitionCounter repCounter : repCounters) {
    int repsBefore = repCounter.getNumRepeats();
    repsAfter = repCounter.addClassificationResult(classification);
    if (repsAfter > repsBefore) {
      // Play a fun beep when rep counter updates.
      ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
      tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
      lastRepResult = String.format(
              Locale.US, "%s : %d reps", repCounter.getClassName(), repsAfter);
      break;
    }

    if (repsAfter == 3){
      //simpan nilai timer dekat sini dulu
      swstopw2();
      tmClass.stopTimer();
      stopwatcher.swstop();
      context.startActivity(intent);
    }

  }
  result.add(lastRepResult);
}
```

Comment: see manifest activity launch mode

Comment: "singleInstance". Should I change it to something else?

Comment: Okay i just change it to singleTask and it works. Thank you!